# Indexing strings to make it easier to search

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to implement searching without using a 3rd party. My current idea is to store different string lengths as keys so that it is indexed quickly. I'd implement a minimum of 3 string lengths and make sure the string being searched is lower case. For instance by data in firebase would look something like this:

```
{
    users: {
        matUserId: {
            name: 'Mathew'
        }
    },
    search: {
        mat: {
            users: { matUserId: true }
        },
        ath: {
            users: { matUserId: true }
        },
        the: {
            users: { matUserId: true }
        },
        hew: {
            users: { matUserId: true }
        },
        math: {
            users: { matUserId: true }
        },
        athe: {
            users: { matUserId: true }
        },
        thew: {
            users: { matUserId: true }
        },
        mathe: {
            users: { matUserId: true }
        },
        athew: {
            users: { matUserId: true }
        },
        mathew: {
            users: { matUserId: true }
        },
    }
}
```

I've made it expandable so if there's other things that can be searched they will share the same search key. I'm confident this will work and be fast (I have a basic implementation to check it out) but was wondering if this is the right way to do searching or if I'm completely off base. As an example if I were to search for the word 'hew' it would just low the child nodes for 'hew' and then I could get the users and display them.

Comment: The right way to do searching depends on your use-case. But as has been answered before: the Firebase Realtime Database is not a full-text search engine. While it is possible to emulate some FTS techniques on it, it's seldom a perfect fit. If you want to search text, it's best to use a dedicated search engine, such as through our Flashlight integration.

Comment: As always thanks for responding Frank. Is there an available tool that doesn't require me to run a separate server? Also is there any issue (beyond having lots of data) in my suggestion above? I don't mind that it handles very specific type of basic string searches.

Comment: Such recommendations are off-topic on Stack Overflow, but I've seen good results with Algolia.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for the tip(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disliked this suggestion I had since it resulted in quite a large dataset. The Algolia suggestion by Frank van Puffelen would work great except I have far too much data for the free version at the moment. I ended up rolling with only being able to search via the start of strings and created a seperate key to store the text in lower case. That way my search became quite a simple query:

```
.orderByChild('searchLowerCase').startAt(query.toLowerCase()).endAt(query.toLowerCase() + "\uf8ff")
```

This will suit my needs.